# how can i pass different objects to a singular object array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

i want to group all my objects together but i think i am going about this the wrong way, my teacher has not explained much about objects in c sharp and i am just wondering what the best method would be for creating, grouping and displaying these objects? any help is much appreciated, i am not sure how to pass objects to an array yet i have looked online for an answer which i did not find and then i was looking at array lists but i am not sure how to initialise or utilise them or if i should even use them and feel i am at a lose here

```
using System;

namespace delivery
{
public abstract class Package
{
    public string fullName { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string zipCode { get; set; }
    public double weight { get; set; }
    public double costPerOunce { get; set; }

    public Package(string fullName, string address, string city, string state, string zipCode)
    {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.costPerOunce = 10.00;
    }

    public Package(double weight)
    {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public virtual double CalculateCost()
    {
        double cost;
        cost = this.weight * this.costPerOunce;
        return cost;
    }
}

public class TwoDayPackage : Package
{
    public double flatFee { get; set; }

    public TwoDayPackage(string fullName, string address, string city, string state, string zipCode) : base(fullName, address, city, state, zipCode)
    {

    }

    public TwoDayPackage(double weight) : base(weight)
    {
        this.flatFee = 10.00;
    }

    public override double CalculateCost()
    {
        double cost = base.CalculateCost() + flatFee;
        return cost;
    }

}

public class OvernightPackage : Package
{
    public double feePerOunce { get; set; }

    public OvernightPackage(string fullName, string address, string city, string state, string zipCode) : base(fullName, address, city, state, zipCode)
    {

    }

    public OvernightPackage(double weight) : base(weight)
    {
        this.feePerOunce = .10;
    }

    public override double CalculateCost()
    {
        double cost = (this.weight * this.feePerOunce) + base.CalculateCost();
        return cost;
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


    }

    public static int ShowMenu()
    {
        int option = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("1.) Create Parcels");
        Console.WriteLine("2.) Display Shipping Details");
        Console.WriteLine("3.) Cost Analysis ");
        Console.WriteLine("4.) Display Couriers Details");
        Console.WriteLine("5.) Exit");
        option = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return option;
    }

    public static void ProcessMenu()
    {
        int response = ShowMenu();
        do
        {
            switch (response)
            {
                case 1:
                    CreateParcels();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    DisplayShippingDetails();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    CostAnalysis();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    DisplayCouriersDetails();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Exit();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("invalid option\n");
                    break;
            }
        } while (response != 5);
    }

    public static void CreateParcels()
    {
        TwoDayPackage s1 = new TwoDayPackage("s1","add1","city1","state1","zip1");
        TwoDayPackage p1 = new TwoDayPackage(5.0);
        TwoDayPackage r1 = new TwoDayPackage("r1", "add2", "city2", "state2", "zip2");
    }
    public static void DisplayShippingDetails()
    {

    }
    public static void CostAnalysis()
    {

    }
    public static void DisplayCouriersDetails()
    {

    }
public static void Exit()
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This looks a little like homework. Even if it's not, I would take a look at generics and collections. The up side to arrays is that they're great for random access, but the down side is that you need to say how big you want the array to be when you create it ("I want an array of Package which can hold 4 elements" for example). Generics can get around this, but aren't as good at random access. Take a look at this (focus on List<T> for now, I guess) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/when-to-use-generic-collections

Comment: It's really quite something, you mention "array" in your title and in the body of your question, yet your code **does not contain a single array** (other than the main parameter)

Comment: i had previously created an array but felt it seemed like the wrong way to go about everything having to create the objects individually and then pass them into an array manually and having long lists of data in the program given the customer details are going to grow at for arguments sake a fast rate

Comment: Most user defined objects (like `Package`, in your example) cannot be displayed directly. Instead, you would add markup (if MVC) or controls (if web forms or Windows forms) to the page and populate those with values that are retrieved from `Package`. Some controls will also let you use something like [DataBind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx) to seamlessly copy the data. None of this has much to do with arrays.

Comment: An array has a fixed size so you'll need a different data structure if you intend to add to it e.g. `List<Product>`.

Comment: @JamieTaylor "Generics can get around this, but aren't as good at random access." - can you please clarify what exactly you was trying to say? Maybe "generic lists has much worse performance for accessing item by index (O(1)) compared to arrays which are much better giving you exactly the same O(1) performance to access item by index".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's what I was driving at. As I was unaware of whether OP understands Big O notation, I thought to leave it as vague for now as I didn't want to overload OP with too many details.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question of how to pass objects into an array. Lets take your

take your package class and lets say you wanted to make a array of them.

1.Declare the type array symbol and a name for your array :

```
Package[] myPackageArray = new Package[3];
```

so know you made your array be able to hold 4 packages. It is 4 because arrays and lists start at 0.

so if you wanted to add a package you need to to tell the array where to put it.

```
Package LApackage = new Package("James","fake st","LA","CA","90210")
Package Neighborpackage = new Package("Mo","1 fake st","LA","CA","90210")
```

lets add it at the first index:

```
myPackageArray[0] = LApackage;

 myPackageArray[1] = Neighborpackage;
```

now to go through them all you use a foreach loop:

```
foreach (Package item in  myPackageArray )
    {
              Console.WriteLine(item.name);//you can choose any propety

    }
```

Comment: thank you, thats exactly what i was wondering, i dunno it just seemed a bit long winded and messy especially when you are adding multiple packages and senders and receivers, thought i was going about it incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a list of type object:

```
var stuff = List<object>()
```

fill it up with whatever you want. Then to iterate over it:

```
foreach(var thing in stuff)
if (thing.GetType() == typeof(SpecificThing))
{
     var tmpThing = thing as SpecificThing
     //Do stuff with tmpThing
}
```

Then you can pull out whatever pieces of 'stuff' you want and cast them to an array using the Lists .ToArray() method.

```
var _SpecificThings = stuff.Select(t => t.GetType() == typeof(SpecificThing)).ToArray()
```